# How can i store variable or to say list variable in the local storage in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I am creating an music player app which needs to list down the music tile after user selected audio files from mobile local storage. So i need to store all the music files path in the local storage so when user selected music one time from local storage he/she did not need to select second time. I does not figure it out how can i do that. I use file_picker for selecting files and path_provider for storing the local data.
Could you please help me with this situation please?

Answer (score 1):

You can store it in shared preferences , add the shared_preferences plugin to the pubspec.yaml file::

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  shared_preferences: "<newest version>"
```

Save data like :

```
// obtain shared preferences
final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

// set value
prefs.setInt('counter', counter);
```

And finally read data using :

```
final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

final counter = prefs.getInt('counter') ?? 0;
```

> Note : Only primitive types can be used: int, double, bool, string, and stringList.
> It’s not designed to store a lot of data.